# How to inject a list or a set in Dagger as we can do it in Spring?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger

Everything is in the question. For instance, for a Foo class containing a list of String :

```
public class Foo {

 private List<String> fooList;

 //getter and setter

}
```

in Xml, we can do the following :

```
<bean id="foo" class="Foo">
  <property name="fooList">
     <list>
        <value>bar</value>
        <value>baz</value>           
    </list>
</property>
```

Comment: Looks like you have to create a Provider for this, see the answer to the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/18105271/2807168

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Dagger you would need to turn your `fooList` into a dependency of your `Foo` class.  You'd do that by annotating it with `@Inject`.  That will tell Dagger that when `Foo` gets created by Dagger, that also `List<String> fooList` needs to be injected.  Keep in mind that the `fooList` isn't private in my example.  Because Dagger doesn't use reflexion and uses code generation instead you have to declare injectable fields as public or private scope.

```
public class Foo {

    @Inject
    @Named("FooDependency")
    List<String> footList;

    // getter and setter

}
```

Here since List is a common type we annotate it with `@Named("FooDependency")` where "FooDependency" can be any string you desire.  We do that because it's at all possible that you'd want to inject another `List<String>` else where in the app and we'd want to be able to differentiate between the 2.  The other `List<String>` could be annotated with `@Named("ADifferentDependency")` for example.

Then you'll need to annotate a method with `@Provide` in one of your modules which would take care of providing that dependency.

```
@Module(injects = Foo.class)
public class SomeModule {
    @Provide
    @Named("FooDependency")
    public List<String> provideFooDependencyListOfString() {
        return Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
    }
}
```

Then you can use it

```
ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new SomeModule());
Foo foo = objectGraph.get(Foo.class);
```