# Sign out from another activity

Tags: android

How to call sign out from another activity when user is logged in using google account. Like in my app there is an activity `LoginActivity` which contains `signin()` and `signout()` methods once this activity has finished it goes to suppose A activity then how to call signout from A activity.

Comment: Can you please share what you have done so far?

Comment: Never try to call methods in an activity from any other class.  The only public methods in a class should be the life cycle methods. Create a class to handle your loging/logout with a static members and static methods - or, better, create a singleton class.

Comment: Instead of having your application logic implemented within the activity, you should rather take that out to an external module and inject it in your activity using Dagger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036933/how-to-set-up-dagger-dependency-injection-from-scratch-in-android-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.The mistake when I call the activity again a new instance got created even the static objects didnt work. So I re initialized the GoogleAPIClient in the activity and in onConnected method I checked for the user if registered then call for signout() or else call signin().