# Dagger - No inject registered for members?

Tags: android, dagger

I have dagger setup and defined injectables correctly, but getting the following errpr:

I saw a couple of similar thread, but the answers didn't solve this

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No inject registered for members/com.aryaxt.app.Pages.LoginActivity. You must explicitly add it to the 'injects' option in one of your modules.**

Module

```
@Module(library = true, injects = {
        LoginActivity.class
})
class MyModule {

    private final Context context;

    public MyModule() {
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    IAuthService provideAuthService() {
        return new AuthService();
    }
}
```

Application

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private ObjectGraph objectGraph;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new MyModule());
    }

    public  ObjectGraph getObjectGraph() {
        return  objectGraph;
    }
}
```

Activity

```
public class LoginActiity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Inject
    IAuthService authService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getObjectGraph().inject(this);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
02-03 07:54:43.934    3305-3305/com.aryaxt.MyApp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.aryaxt.MyApp, PID: 3305
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aryaxt.MyApp/com.aryaxt.MyApp.Pages.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No inject registered for members/com.aryaxt.MyApp.Pages.LoginActivity. You must explicitly add it to the 'injects' option in one of your modules.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No inject registered for members/com.aryaxt.MyApp.Pages.LoginActivity. You must explicitly add it to the 'injects' option in one of your modules.
            at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.getInjectableTypeBinding(ObjectGraph.java:302)
            at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.inject(ObjectGraph.java:279)
            at com.aryaxt.bobber.Pages.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:18)
            at com.aryaxt.bobber.Pages.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Try using this setup based on android-bootstrap: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27036934/2413303

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No proguard

Comment: Please try the setup I linked, although it should work. I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: This particular example does not even compile for a number of reasons. I'm assuming you've removed unnecessary code (which is good!), but perhaps a bit too much. After the compiler errors have been fixed, this particular example should work. Into solving the issue: remove the `library = true` statement. *Never* use `library=true` or `complete=false` if you don't know exactly what its doing. If you do this, you will get an error during compile-time which should tell you more.