# [Dagger 1.x]: Specifying the ObjectGraph itself as a dependency for a class?

Tags: android, dagger

### TL;DR;

**Is it acceptable for a class to depend on the ObjectGraph itself?**

---

I need this because I need to inject dependencies on some objects that I load at runtime - at a time that is disconnected from the point at which the ObjectGraph is initialized. Here is an example that illustrates how I use `ServiceLoader` framework to load concrete implementation classes of a Service at runtime, and then inject dependencies into the loaded implementation classes.

```
interface Plugin {
    void doSomething();
}

class AwesomePlugin implements plugin {
    @Inject DependencyOne dependencyOne; 
    @Inject DependencyTwo dependencyTwo;
    void doSomething(){
        // ...some implementation...
    }
}

class PluginEngine{
    public void start(){
        ServiceLoader<Plugin> pluginLoader = ServiceLoader.load(Plugin.class);
        for(Plugin plugin: pluginLoader){
            //TODO: Inject plugin dependencies here
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this would require the `PluginEngine` class to have access to the `ObjectGraph` instance:

```
class PluginEngine{
    private final ObjectGraph objectGraph;
    
    public PluginEngine(ObjectGraph graph){
        this.objectGraph = graph;
    }
    
    public void start(){
        ServiceLoader<Plugin> pluginLoader = ServiceLoader.load(Plugin.class);
        for(Plugin plugin: pluginLoader){
            objectGraph.inject(plugin);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a code smell? Is this pointing to some problem elsewhere in my code, or in the way my dependencies are set up?

While composing this question, I began to see the role of Dagger as a means of replacing arbitrary dependencies with a dependency on the `ObjectGraph` itself. On Android, you use a reference to the custom `Application` sub-class and use it to perform injection - which is basically just a means to get access to the `ObjectGraph` itself. Is this reasoning flawed?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce This is for Dagger 1.x. Edited the title to clarify this. IIRC, Dagger2 does not have the ObjectGraph at all.

Comment: Ah, okay. I was curious because I haven't used Dagger2 (only Dagger1), but never encountered the `ServiceLoader<T>`. Is that your own code? I don't think you can obtain the `@Inject Objectgraph objectGraph` dependency without... well, injecting it with `objectGraph.inject(this)`, for which you'd need `objectGraph` which you cannot inject without itself, therefore I don't think this will work, unless there's something here that I don't see.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ServiceLoader is a general Java facility for loading concrete implementation classes at runtime. Here's the link to the docs from Android - but it is available in other Java implementations as well - https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ServiceLoader.html.

You're right about not being able to inject the ObjectGraph itself. I should probably move it into a constructor argument.

Comment: Ah. I'll read about ServiceLoaders then. I personally used the following setup, snatched the structure from the code generated by `Android Bootstrap`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27036934/2413303

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, it looks like this is acceptable. The [u2020 sample app](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020) does something roughly similar. In fact it makes some very clever use of `getSystemService()` to achieve this but that is Android specific. In particular, look at [`Injector.java`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/5991f2ea01f14cc68b6c54b03980e4f91feaa0ff/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/u2020/data/Injector.java) and how it is used from within custom views like [`TrendingView`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/0e6d4776331880443e7f409b93cf9b5cf67e96ae/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/u2020/ui/trending/TrendingView.java)

So, conceptually, one could do something like this - which basically abstracts the concrete `ObjectGraph` dependency behind an `Injector` interface.

```
class PluginEngine{
    private final Injector injector;

    public PluginEngine(Injector injector){
        this.injector = injector;
    }

    public void start(){
        ServiceLoader<Plugin> pluginLoader = ServiceLoader.load(Plugin.class);
        for(Plugin plugin: pluginLoader){
            injector.inject(plugin);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be refined/adjusted in various ways such that the injector dependency is provided via a constructor or obtained in other ways.