# Dagger injects, complete confusion

Tags: android, dagger

I'm using `dagger:1.2.2`. There're two modules. BaseModule serves an EventBus for an `Activity` and ActivityModule serves NavigationController for the same `Activity`.

```
@Module(injects = { `does NOT have MainActivity.class registered`},
     library = true
)
public class BaseModule {
    @Provides @Singleton public EventBus provideEventBus() {
        return DefaultEventBus.create();
    }

    @Provides @Singleton public Application provideApplication() {
        return mApp;
    }

    @Provides @IsTablet public boolean isTablet(Application app) {
        return app.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet);
    }
}

@Module(
     addsTo = BaseModule.class,
     injects = MainActivity.class
)
public class ActivityModule {
    @Provides
    NavigationController provideNavigationController(Application app,@IsTablet boolean isTablet) {
         return new NavigationController(app, isTablet);
    }
}
```

`Activity`'s fields:

```
@Inject
EventBus mEventBus;

@Inject
NavigationController mNavigationController;
```

NavigationController's ugly ctor:

```
public NavigationController(Context context, FragmentManager fm, List<Behaviour> behaviourList, @Nullable Class lastRoot,
                                @IsTablet boolean isTablet, Application application) {
```

This code passes static validation and performs well with

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ObjectGraph activityGraph = getBaseModuleGraph(this).plus(new ActivityModule(this));
    activityGraph.inject(this);
}
```

It crushes as expected due to unsatisfied dependency provided by `ActivityModule` if i just apply:

```
getBaseModuleGraph(this).inject(this);
```

The thing that bugs me is that `BaseModule`'s inject doesn't contain `MainActivity` while it provides `EventBus` dependency for it. If I add this inject it gonna complain about unresolved NavigationController that is provided by ActivityModule. Setting complete=false on the `BaseModule` results in runtime exception

> NavigationController has no injectable members. Do you want to add an
>   injectable constructor? required by class
>   MainActivity

I don't quite get it.

Ultimately I wanted `BaseModule`'s injects to be more explicit by including `MainActivity` because it provides `EventBus` as I mentioned.

Could you help me out understanding it?

Comment: you should totally show the missing `{...}` in your code, for the base and activity modules. At least for the classes that you have trouble with (`NavigationController`)

Comment: That is wonderful, but I can't see the problem without seeing the `@Provides` methods (or injectable constructor), and where you want to use this in your activity (`@Inject Whatever whatever` and `public void onCreate(...) { super.onCreate(...); getBaseModuleGraph(this).inject(this);`) so it would be nice if those were added to the question.

Comment: where do you get `(Application app,@IsTablet boolean isTablet)` the two parameters from? The object graph doesn't seem to know about them. Although to be honest, you are not passing them to the navigation controller either, so I don't see their purpose.

Comment: So, what do u have to say now?

Comment: add `(complete=false, library=true)` to ActivityModule and see if it fixes the problem - if not, just remove the two parameters from `provideNavigationController(Application app,@IsTablet boolean isTablet)` as you don't seem to be using them. But if you **are** using them, then change the constructor of `NavigationController` to receive the two parameters you get in the `provides` method.

Comment: Changed NavigationController and added (complete=false, library=true). The same issue: NavigationController has no injectable members. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by class MainActivity

Comment: can you show how you the `NavigationController` class is initialized?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, added to the description. I feel like its not going anywhere, but anyway great thanks for the effort. I might try the problem on a separate project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75181/discussion-between-midnight-and-epicpandaforce).

Comment: Hmm. I'm stumped. Especially with that giga-constructor, haha. Not sure how the other constructor compiles if this is the one you use, but okay. Anyways, what I used for Dagger was this setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036933/how-to-set-up-dagger-dependency-injection-from-scratch-in-android-project I'm not sure if it'll help, though.

Comment: Look into http://antonioleiva.com/dagger-3/ and see what he does differently