# Unit testing a simple class (with Dagger 1.2)

Tags: android, junit, mockito, dagger

I think I have some unit testing-dagger missed.

I am trying to test a class which implements this Interface:

```
public interface GetAndroidOSVersionInteractor {
    public String execute ();
}
```

The class is this one:

```
public class GetAndroidOSVersionInteractorImpl implements GetAndroidOSVersionInteractor {

    @Inject
    public GetAndroidOSVersionInteractorImpl (){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        String version = "android: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + " device: " + Build.MANUFACTURER + Build.MODEL;
        return(version);
    }
}
```

Its inject module is this one:

```
@Module(library = true, complete = false)
public class InteractorsModule {

    @Provides
        GetAndroidOSVersionInteractor provideGetAndroidOSVersionInteractor(GetAndroidOSVersionInteractorImpl getAndroidOSVersionInteractorImpl) {
            return getAndroidOSVersionInteractorImpl;
        }
}
```

But when I execute this test, it always return a -1 NullPointerException:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GetAndroidOSVersionInteractorTest extends TestCase {

    GetAndroidOSVersionInteractor getAndroidOSVersionInteractor;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void executeTest(){
        final String os = getAndroidOSVersionInteractor.execute();
        assertNotNull(os);
    }

}
```

What am I missing? Is it a problem with Dagger 1.2? 
Could you explain me why this doesn't work?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need the following:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GetAndroidOSVersionInteractorTest extends TestCase {
    @Inject // <-- this
    GetAndroidOSVersionInteractor getAndroidOSVersionInteractor;
```

and

```
private ObjectGraph testObjectGraph;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    testObjectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new MockModule());
    testObjectGraph.inject(this);
}
```

and

```
@Module(injects={GetAndroidOSVersionInteractorTest.class}, includes={InteractorsModule.class})
public class MockModule {
}
```

Comment: I do not understand very well what MockModule does. I think that I need to inject manually my dependencies via ObjectGraph, but I am not sure what this class does. Please, correct me if I am wrong. Thx.

Comment: You need to create a root module that includes your modules, and also specifies that it injects the test classes. For more information, check out my Dagger1 guide: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27036934/2413303