# Pure Junit testing in Android studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, junit, gradle

I've managed to setup a java test in my project however I've fallen into two different pitfalls.

1) I make a Java module, I can run it and do some arbitrary tests but since my Viewmodels/presenters/models are all in my Android project it means I cannot get the objects. That's a pretty big problem, I suppose an alternative would be to create a module for just the Presenters or ViewModels + Models.. but that seems bad

2) I make a folder under src/test/java/...  however when I'm in there and try to compile, due to the lambda expressions in my project I end up getting weird compilation errors due to retrolambda.

```
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for java.lang.invoke.MethodType not found
```

How do I go about setting up my gradle to testCompile in a way where Retrolambda isn't messing things up? Below is my gradle for the project

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.3"
    }
}

apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.patrykpoborca.cleanarchitecture"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        encoding "UTF-8"
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    dependencies {
        apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
        testApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
        //needed to resolve compilation errors, thanks to tutplus.org for finding the dependency
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036933/how-to-set-up-dagger-dependency-injection-from-scratch-in-android-project
        //test compiles
        androidTestApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'

        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
        provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'


        androidTestCompile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
        testCompile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
        // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
        androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        }
        androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
        androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
    }
}
```

P.s. does anyone know how to set a Java module's JavaVersion? In my java module Lambda's compiled despite being told that the version of java was wrong... really weird, here's the gradle of the java module. Thanks!

```
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.3"
    }
}

apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"

dependencies {
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    testCompile project(':app')
}
```