# Questions about Android with RxAndroid, Dagger 2 and Realm

Tags: android, realm, dagger-2, rx-android

I'm currently working on an App and wanted to use the current state of the art libaries for Android: RxAndroid, Dagger2 and Realm. I couldn't find good examples in the net, so I have to ask here.

## 1. Why should I use Observable as return type for Realm queries?

```
public Observable<Bla> getBla() {
    Bla b = realm.where(Bla.class).findFirst();
    return Observable.just(b);
}
```

In most cases Realm queries run on UIThread, so why I shound't just return the result as List instead of

```
Observable<List<Bla>>
```

Maybe someone knows a very good example with realm in this lib conbination?

## 2. Why I am able to inject a Service without mention a provider in the module. Is something wrong in my construction?

```
@Inject
TableService mTableService;
```

(Code below)

## 3. ServiceComponent needs Application from AppComponent, how to configure @Component correctly?

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, ServiceModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, ServiceModule.class})
public interface ServiceComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}

public class AppModule {

    Application mApplication;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application providesApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    RealmConfiguration provideRealmConfiguration(Application application) {
        return new RealmConfiguration.Builder(application)
               .schemaVersion(1)
               .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
               .build();
    }

    @Provides
    Realm provideRealm(RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration) {
        try {
            return Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
            return Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
        }
    }
}

@Module
public class ServiceModule {

    public ServiceModule() {
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    GuestService provideGuestService(Realm realm) {
        return new GuestService(realm);
    }
}

public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    private AppComponent mAppComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();

    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return mAppComponent;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) `RealmResults<T>` is auto-updating, and if you add a `RealmChangeListener` to your `RealmResults`, then it will be called whenever the underlying data has changed.

```
private final RealmChangeListener listener = new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(Object results) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

But when you call `asObservable()` on a `RealmResults`, then an `Observable<RealmResults<T>>` is created that automatically appends a `RealmChangeListener` that notifies you of changes, and removes it when you unsubscribe. You can look at the exact behavior if you check the default [RealmObservableFactory](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory.java#L127-L161) implementation.

So it really is a shorthand for adding a `RealmChangeListener` to your results so that you can update your views whenever.

```
Subscription subscription = RxTextView.textChanges(editText).switchMap(charSequence -> 
    realm.where(SomeObject.class)
         .contains("searchField", charSequence.toString(), Case.INSENSITIVE)
         .findAllAsync()
         .asObservable())
.filter(RealmResults::isLoaded) //
.subscribe(objects -> adapter.updateData(objects));
```

2.) You probably have specified an `@Inject` annotated constructor.

```
public class TableService {
    @Inject
    Application application;

    @Inject
    public TableService() {
    }
}
```

3.) [Typically you should have 1 component / scope.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545075/dagger2-and-android/40546157#40546157)

EDIT:

> 1. Why should I use Observable as return type for Realm queries?

```
public Observable<Bla> getBla() {
    Bla b = realm.where(Bla.class).findFirst();
    return Observable.just(b);
}
```

This doesn't really make sense to use with Realm, because it doesn't listen to changes.

It's more reasonable to use

```
public Observable<Blah> getBla() {
    Blah blah = realm.where(Blah.class).findFirst();
    if(blah == null) {
        return Observable.empty();
    } else {
        return blah.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Although [personally I advise to use `Observable<RealmResults<T>>` because it is more reliable.](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3138)

> 3.) Not sure what you mean. Service Component is not working without @component appModule.class, but it should be in my understanding.

There shouldn't even **be** a `ServiceComponent`. Just `@Component SingletonComponent`.

Comment: 1. I'm not about using RealmResults, I ment alternatively to return the Object like "public Bla getBla() { ...}" Would it be somehow bad?

2. Ya I did. thanks!

3. Not sure what you mean. Service Component is not working without @component appModule.class, but it should be in my understanding.