# Implementing a simple Dagger2 sample

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm new using Dagger2 (I always used Koin) and I'm trying to implement a simple sample but I don't really know what I'm missing. This is what I got so far.

*app.gradle*:

```
ext.daggerVersion = '2.23.2'

implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
```

*AppModule.kt*:

```
@Module
class AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(app: App): Application = app

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideTestOperator(testOperator: TestOperator) = testOperator

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideTestClass(testClass: TestClass) = testClass

}
```

*AppComponent.kt*:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidInjectionModule::class,
    AppModule::class
])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(app: App): Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

*TestClass.kt* & *TestOperator.kt* in the same file:

```
class TestClass @Inject constructor(private val testOperator: TestOperator) {
    fun getRandomValueFromCTest(): Int = testOperator.generateRandomNumber()
}

class TestOperator @Inject constructor() {
    fun generateRandomNumber(): Int = Random.nextInt()
}
```

*App.kt*:

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this@App).build()
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.kt*:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var testClass: TestClass

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val x = testClass.getRandomValueFromCTest()
    }
}
```

> Error: testClass == null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*AppModule.kt*: Provide the application context. No need to write @singleton @provides for your Test* classes (will see why)

```
@Module
class AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(app: App): Context = app.applicationContext
}
```

*AppComponent.kt*: `@Component.Builder` is deprecated IIRC. Use `@Component.Factory`. And replace `AndroidInjectionModule::class` with `AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class` since we are using `dagger-android-support` and android's `*Compat*` stuff. Refer a new module here called `ActivityModule::class`.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    ActivityModule::class
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    AppModule::class
])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Factory
    abstract class Factory : AndroidInjector.Factory<App>
}
```

*TestClass.kt & TestOperator.kt*: Since you were providing singletons by writing @singleton and @provides method, I assume you want them to be singletons. Just annotate the class definition with @Singleton and dagger will take care of it. No need to write @Provides methods.

```
@Singleton
class TestClass @Inject constructor(private val testOperator: TestOperator) {
    fun getRandomValueFromCTest(): Int = testOperator.generateRandomNumber()
}

@Singleton
class TestOperator @Inject constructor() {
    fun generateRandomNumber(): Int = Random.nextInt()
}
```

*App.kt*: Using factory instead of builder since `@Component.Builder` is deprecated.

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(this)
    }
}
```

*ActivityModule.kt*: Provide a module to dagger to create your activities.

```
@Module
interface ActivityModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    fun provideMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

*MainActivity.kt*: Finally, extend from `DaggerAppCompatActivity`.

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var testClass: TestClass

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val x = testClass.getRandomValueFromCTest()
    }
}
```

I believe this should run without issues. For more reference you could look into this [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di) and the new simpler docs at [dagger.dev/android](https://dagger.dev/android)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the actual injection call.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  @Inject
  lateinit var testClass: TestClass

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      AndroidInjection.inject(this)
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`MainActivity` should extends `DaggerActivity`, not `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: It's not true, actually. It may extend `DaggerActivity` but it is not required. It's enough to call `AndroidInjection.inject(/* ... */)` in `onCreate(/* ... */)` method.