# How to provide context with Dagger 2?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I'm creating application which uses Dagger to inject some dependencies.

I created some module classes but one of them needs context. The problem is that i don't know how to provide context in a correct way. I tried a lot of solutions but everytime i get an exception:

> @Component.Builder is missing setters for required modules or components: [com.mamak.geobaza.di.ContextModule]

What should I do to provide context in a correct way?

**ApiModule.kt**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.mamak.geobaza.utils.AppConstans.BASE_URL
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module(includes = [
    RxJavaModule::class,
    OkHttpModule::class
])
class ApiModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun gson(): Gson {
        return GsonBuilder().create()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun gsonConverterFactory(gson: Gson): GsonConverterFactory {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun retrofit(
        okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        gsonConverterFactory: GsonConverterFactory,
        rxJava2CallAdapterFactory: RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
    ): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJava2CallAdapterFactory)
            .build()
    }
}
```

**InterfaceModule.kt**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import android.content.Context
import com.mamak.geobaza.ui.`interface`.ProjectListItemInterfaceImpl
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module(includes = [
    ContextModule::class
])
class InterfaceModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun projectListItemInterface(context: Context): ProjectListItemInterfaceImpl {
        return ProjectListItemInterfaceImpl(context)
    }
}
```

**OkHttpModule.kt**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
class OkHttpModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun okHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        return HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun okHttpClient(httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
    }
}
```

**ProjectApiModule.kt**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import com.mamak.geobaza.network.api.ProjectApiService
import dagger.Module
import retrofit2.Retrofit

@Module(includes = [
    ApiModule::class
])
class ProjectApiModule {
    fun projectApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ProjectApiService {
        return retrofit.create(ProjectApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

**RxJavaModule.kt**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
class RxJavaModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun rxJavaCallAdapterFactory(): RxJava2CallAdapterFactory {
        return RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
    }
}
```

**ViewModelKey.kt**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import dagger.MapKey
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

**ViewModelModule.kt**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.mamak.geobaza.factory.ViewModelFactory
import com.mamak.geobaza.ui.viewmodel.ProjectListViewModel
import dagger.Binds
import dagger.Module
import dagger.multibindings.IntoMap

@Module
internal abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun viewModelFactory(viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ProjectListViewModel::class)
    protected abstract fun projectListViewModel(projectListViewModel: ProjectListViewModel): ViewModel

}
```

**ContextModule.kt**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import android.content.Context
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides

@Module
class ContextModule constructor(val context: Context) {
    @Provides
    fun context(): Context {
        return context
    }
}
```

**AppComponent.kt**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import android.app.Application
import dagger.BindsInstance
import dagger.Component
import dagger.android.support.AndroidSupportInjectionModule
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    ApiModule::class,
    ViewModelModule::class,
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    InterfaceModule::class,
    ContextModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        @BindsInstance
        fun apiModule(apiModule: ApiModule): Builder

        @BindsInstance
        fun interfaceModule(interfaceModule: InterfaceModule): Builder

        @BindsInstance
        fun contextModule(contextModule: ContextModule): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(appController: AppController)
}
```

**AppController.kt**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import android.app.Application

import dagger.android.AndroidInjector
import dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector
import dagger.android.HasAndroidInjector
import javax.inject.Inject

class AppController : Application(), HasAndroidInjector {
    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerAppComponent.Builder()
            .application(this)
            .apiModule(ApiModule())
            .interfaceModule(InterfaceModule())
            .contextModule(ContextModule(this))
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at google sample related to using Dagger? https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/di/ApplicationModule.java

Comment: Can you instantiate your `contextModule` before `interfaceModule` in your component builder inside `Application` class ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58009504/implementing-a-simple-dagger2-sample

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I'll try to use them in my project or connect them to answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are all good at using @Component.Builder but it can be further optimized.

Following are the changes:

**Step 1 : Use `@Binds` in Context Module to provide `Context`**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import android.content.Context
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides

@Module
abstract class ContextModule {  // to allow abstract method make module abstract

  //@Binds works on an abstract method

    @Singleton
    @Binds   // @Binds, binds the Application instance to Context
    abstract fun context(appInstance:Application): Context //just return the super-type you need 

}
```

**Step 2 : Remove redundant code from `AppComponent`**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import android.app.Application
import dagger.BindsInstance
import dagger.Component
import dagger.android.support.AndroidSupportInjectionModule
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    ApiModule::class,
    ViewModelModule::class,
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    InterfaceModule::class,
    ContextModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        @BindsInstance
        fun apiModule(apiModule: ApiModule): Builder

        @BindsInstance
        fun interfaceModule(interfaceModule: InterfaceModule): Builder

       // @BindsInstance   //this two  commented lines can be removed 
       // fun contextModule(contextModule: ContextModule): Builder

       // why? because dagger already knows how to provide Context Module 

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(appController: AppController)
}
```

**Step 3: Modify the Component Builder to take advantage of `@Component.Builder` and `@Binds`**

```
package com.mamak.geobaza.di

import android.app.Application

import dagger.android.AndroidInjector
import dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector
import dagger.android.HasAndroidInjector
import javax.inject.Inject

class AppController : Application(), HasAndroidInjector {
    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerAppComponent.Builder()
            .application(this)
            .apiModule(ApiModule())
            .interfaceModule(InterfaceModule())
           // .contextModule(ContextModule(this)) //this line can be removed 
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok everything works fine instead of InterfaceModule. When i use @Inject annotation on ProjectListItemInterfaceImpl in my activity, i get an exception - lateinit property projectListItemInterfaceImpl has not been initialized.

Comment: I created PicassoModule which provides Picasso. When i use context to create Picasso object everything works. Picasso is initialized properly in my activity. It seems that i made a mistake creating an InterfaceModule or just the ProjectListItemInterfaceImpl. So, thank you so much for your answer. Now providing context in my project works!

Answer (score 3):

By using the `component factory` method, you can avoid instantiating a module manually. Please check the example below.

```
@Component(
    modules = [ApplicationModule::class]
)
@Singleton
interface ApplicationComponent {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): ApplicationComponent
    }
}
```

And in your application class, initialize the object graph like the following

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    lateinit var applicationComponent: ApplicationComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.factory().create(this)
    }
}
```

Now the `context` will be available in your object graph to be injected anywhere.

Comment: Should one use a qualifier like `fun create(@BindsInstance @AppContext context: Context): ApplicationComponent` in order to differentiate it from say Activity context? Plus does one need to add a module with contexts or is that unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

add a new Module by adding below codes

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule(var app: App) {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApp(): App = app

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(): Context = app.applicationContext
}
```

and then add this module into your component interface

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ApplicationModule::class))
```

lastly create your component in your Application(`class App : android.app.Application()`) class

```
val component by lazy {
    DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
            .build()
}
```

Comment: It works as before but now i'm getting: @Component.Builder is missing setters for required modules or components: [com.mamak.geobaza.di.ApplicationModule].

Comment: because your setup is different from this one

Comment: please delete all your components and then setup live above and then add modules accordingly

Comment: I followed your steps and still have the same error. @iCantC above answer works but ProjectListItemInterfaceImpl(provided by InterfaceModule) which needs context is still uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

All the code from previous answers is not longer necessary, simply use `@ApplicationContext` where context is needed:

```
@Provides
fun provideFirebaseAnalytics(@ApplicationContext context: Context) =
    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context)
```