# Dagger2 dependency Cycle by Using @Binds and @Inject fields

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am getting a dependency cycle whenever I try to use a subcomponent with binding objects. I have an app scope and an activity scope.  At the app scope I create my web service then when the activity opens I want to create a storage object, controller, and navigator (all custom classes not androidx classes) and inject them into my androidx ViewModel class.  But when I do so I get a dependency cycle.

My top level component looks like

```
@AppScope
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

  val activityComponentBuilder: ActivityComponent.Builder
}

@Module(subcomponents = [ActivityComponent::class])
interface AppModule {

  @Binds
  fun mockWebService(mockWebService: MockWebService): MockWebService
}
```

Next my subcomponent looks like

```
@ActivityComponent
@Subcomponent(modules = [ActivityModule::class])
interface ActivityComponent {

  fun inject(sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel)

  @Subcomponent.Builder
  interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun storage(storage: Storage): Builder

    fun build(): ActivityComponent
  }
}
```

In my activity module I bind two objects

```
  @Binds
  abstract fun controller(controller: Controller): Controller

  @Binds
  abstract fun navigator(navigator: Navigator): Navigator
```

Each object has an @Inject constructor

```
class Navigator @Inject constructor(private val storage: Storage)

class Controller @Inject constructor(
  private val webService: MockWebService,
  private val navigator: Navigator,
  private val storage: Storage
) {
```

Inside my shared view model I try to build my component and inject the fields

```
  @Inject
  lateinit var navigator: Navigator
  @Inject
  lateinit var controller: Controller

  init {
      MainApplication.component.activityComponentBuilder
        .storage(InMemoryStorage.from(UUID.randomUUID().toString()))
        .build()
        .inject(this)

  }
```

But dagger won't build.  I get an error

```
[Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle: public abstract interface AppComponent {

MockWebService is injected at di.AppModule.mockWebService(mockWebService)
MockWebService is injected at ActivityModule.Controller(webService, …)
Controller is injected at SharedViewModel.controller
SharedViewModel is injected at
```

But the error message cuts off there. Am I missing something in how to use a subcomponent to put objects on the graph and then inject them into an object?  Is this not possible with Dagger?

Comment: `@Binds` is used to let dagger know the different implementations of an interface. You don't need `@binds` here since `Navigator` and `Controller` are normal classes that do not implement any interface. I'd assume that's the case with `MockWebService` too. Also, those classes have `@Inject constructor`, which means dagger can instantiate them and you don't need to write `@Provides` too

Comment: But without `@Binds` will the `MockWebService` be scoped to the application scope?

Comment: Can you post the class declration of `MockWebService`?

Comment: `@Binds` isn't doing any scoping. Its only job is to tell dagger about different implementations. You can add `@XScope` with `@Binds` to make some object scoped. Or, you could just add the scope annotation to the class declaration.

Comment: Oh you can add an `@Scope` annotation on an `@Inject` constructor? 
`MockWebService` is currently an object with an empty constructor so nothing interesting there

Comment: Not on the constructor but on the class. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58009976/2235972). As for the dependency cycle, I think it's because you're telling `ActivityComponent` to use `ActivityModule` and telling `ActivityModule` to install `ActivityComponent`. Doing just either one should be the case (I think)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: I'll add this as an answer for future readers who will stumble upon this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Binds` is used to let dagger know the different implementations of an interface. You don't need `@Binds` here since Navigator and Controller are simple classes that do not implement any interface. I'd assume that's the case with MockWebService too. Also, those classes have `@Inject constructor`, which means dagger can instantiate them and we don't need to write extra `@Provides` functions for those classes.

`@Binds` isn't doing any scoping. Its only job is to tell dagger about different implementations. You can add `@XScope` with `@Binds` to make some object scoped. Or, you could just add the scope annotation to the class declaration. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58009976/2235972) an example of how you can add scope to class declaration.

As for the dependency cycle, I think it's because you're telling `ActivityComponent` to use `ActivityModule` and telling `ActivityModule` to install `ActivityComponent`. Doing just either one should be the case (I think).