# Dagger: Inject named string in constructor

Tags: properties, dependency-injection, dagger

I have a properties file and I would like to inject a property in a service.

I would like use the constructor method for DI like this:

```
@Inject
public ScanService(@Named("stocks.codes") String codes, IYahooService yahooService) {
    this.yahooService = yahooService;
    this.codes = codes;
}
```

I try to do a module like specified in this link => [Dagger: Inject @Named strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099909/dagger-inject-named-strings)

```
@Provides
@Named("stocks.code")
public String providesStocksCode() {
    return "test";
}
```

And for the provider method for my service:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public IScanService provideScanService(String codes, IYahooService yahooService){
    return new ScanService(codes, yahooService);
}
```

When I run the compilation I get this error:

> [ERROR]
>   /Users/stocks/src/main/java/net/modules/TestModule.java:[22,7]
>   error: No injectable members on java.lang.String. Do you want to add
>   an injectable constructor? required by
>   provideScanService(java.lang.String,net.IYahooService)
>   for net.modules.TestModule

How can I inject my property correctly in the constructor ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two different names: `stocks.codes` and `stocks.code`.

You will also have to annotate your `provideScanService` `codes` parameter:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public IScanService provideScanService(@Named("stocks.codes") String codes, IYahooService yahooService){
    return new ScanService(codes, yahooService);
}
```

Or do it like this:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public IScanService provideScanService(ScanService scanService){
    return scanService;
}
```

Comment: :( Thanks a lot. I didn't see the bad name in @Named. Sorry for this bad question

Answer (score 10):

If you mean Dagger 2, I can help you.
First you have to declare dependencies in Component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(BaseActivity baseActivity);

    @Named("cloud") UserDataSource userCloudSource();
    @Named("disc") UserDataSource userDiscSource(); 
    UserDataRepository userDataRepository();  
}
```

then instantiate it in Module

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    @Provides @Named("cloud")
    UserDataSource provideCloudUserSource(UserCloudSource userSource) {
        return userSource;
    }

    @Provides @Named("disc")
    UserDataSource provideDiscUserSource(UserDiscSource userSource) {
        return userSource;
    }

    @Provides
    UserDataRepository provideUserRepository(UserDataRepository repository) {
        return repository;
    }

}
```

then inject it in constructor with @Named qualifiers

```
@Inject
public UserDataRepository(@Named("cloud") UserDataSource cloudSource, 
     @Named("disc") UserDataSource discSource) {
    this.cloudDataSource= cloudSource;
    this.discDataSource = discSource;
}
```

Comment: No bro, it's working, if it's not work than you doing something wrong