# How to inject a Retrofit object directly into a repository class?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I want to inject a `Retrofit` object directly into my `MyRepository` class but I always get a `NullPointerException`. This is what I have tried.

This is my `AppModule` class:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    static Retrofit provideRetrofitInstance(){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
}
```

And this is my view model class:

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    LiveData<Data> myLiveData;

    MyViewModel(Application application, City city) {
        super(application);
        myLiveData = myRepository.addDataToLiveData(city);
    }

    LiveData<Data> getLiveData() {
        return myLiveData;
    }
}
```

And this is my repository class where I want to inject Retofit:

```
public class MyRepository {
    private String myTex;
    @Inject
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    public MyRepository(String myText) {
        this.myText = myText;
    }

    LiveData<Data> addDataToLiveData(City city) {
        //Make api call using retrofit
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

This is how I instantiate my `ViewModel` in my activity class:

```
MyRepository repository = new MyRepository("MyText");
Application application = activity.getApplication();
MyViewModelFactory factory = new MyViewModelFactory(application, repository);
MyViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Comment: How are you injecting the retrofit instance? Are you calling `inject(this)` somewhere in your repository? Is your Repository injectable itself? In which case you could use constructor injection.

Comment: "How are you injecting the retrofit instance?" using @Inject annotation. "Are you calling inject(this) somewhere in your repository?" No, I'm not. How can I do that? "Is your Repository injectable itself?" How I check that out? "In which case you could use constructor injection." How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making your Repository injectable is the simplest solution, which also allows you to inject it where it's used, in your `ViewModel`s or `Interactor`s:

```
@Singleton
public class MyRepository {

    private Retrofit retrofit;

    @Inject
    public MyRepository(Retrofit retrofit) {
        this.retrofit = retrofit;
    }

    LiveData<Data> addDataToLiveData(City city) {
        //Make api call using retrofit
    }
}
```

Edit: you can either provide the text via Dagger and inject that in your constructor, like this

```
@Inject
public MyRepository(String myText, Retrofit retrofit)
```

Note that you'd need to use `@Named` or `@Qualifier` for your string.

Alternatively, you can inject your repository calling `inject(this)`, the syntax depends on how you setup Dagger

```
somehowGetDaggerComponent().inject(this)
```

I strongly suggest you go with the 1st solution.

Comment: Please check my updated question. I already have a constructor. Sorry for not providing all the data from the beginning.

Comment: Where should I add `@Named` or `@Qualifier` annotations?

Comment: Where you provide the string , in the dagger module. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099909/dagger-inject-named-strings

Comment: I more confused now. I my `ViewModel` class, I construct a new object of my `MyRepository` class using `new` keyword. And now Android Studio complaines that I need to pass to the constructor a `Retrofit` object which I don't have there. I only have the string value. I just want to get injected only here. Beside that my String is dynamic and not static.

Comment: You should not instantiate the repository with new, simply define it as an injected dependency in your viewmodel.

Comment: I don't think this is so simple possible because in order to do that, I cannot use new keyword when constructing new object of my ViewModel class.

Comment: That's the whole idea behind Dagger, you don't `new` dependencies, they get injected. The solution I highlighted is best practice, injecting your repository and having the repository dependencies themselves injected.

Comment: Ok and that case, how can I instantiate in my `AppModule` class `MyRepository` object, so it can be injected?

Comment: If you use constructor injection, like in my example, you don't need a module to instantiate your repository.

Comment: Couldn't make it work, I'll try in another way. Voted-up for giving some new insights. Thanks

Comment: Finally did it. Thanks you.

Comment: Great, glad I could help.

Comment: Maybe you can also help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173074/how-to-pass-a-string-to-a-viewmodel-repository-class-using-dagger2-in-android